# Inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$  be a space vector over $\mathbb C$.
And let $T$ be linear transformation $T\colon V \to V $.

Suppose that $ \langle T(v), v\rangle = 0  $ for each $ v \in V$.

Prove that $T=0 $.

I was thinking - if we fix $v\in V $ , we could than chose $u \in V $ such that 
$\langle T(u),u\rangle = 0  $ will imply  $T(v) = 0$.

Am I in the right direction ? or is there another way of proving that claim ?
And, another question - is this claim is true over $\mathbb R$?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I thinki you must require $\;T\;$ to be self adjoint (hermitic or complex symmetric), otherwise the claim is false. For example, let $\;T\;$ be rotation in $\;\frac\pi2\;$ radians...

Comment: Surprisingly, this result holds for any operator on a complex dimensional vector space. Over a real vector space, it indeed holds only under the additional assumption that $T$ is self-adjoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $g \colon V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $g(v,w) = \left< Tv, w \right>$. Then $g$ is a sesquilinear form on $V$ and so by the polarization identity (a direct computation which doesn't use the specific form of $g$, only the sesquilinearity) we have:

$$ g(x,y) = \frac{1}{4} \left( g(x + y, x + y) - g(x - y, x - y) + ig(x + iy, x + iy) -ig(x - iy, x - iy) \right) $$

for all $x, y \in V$. Since $g(v,v) = 0$ for all $v \in V$ we get that $g(v,w) = 0$ for all $v,w \in V$. In particular, $g(v,Tv) = \left< Tv, Tv \right> = ||Tv||^2 = 0$ and so $Tv = 0$ for all $v \in V$.

Comment: The polarization identity assumes conjugate symmetry of $g$, which is not a given.

Comment: @qman I assume that the inner product the OP was working with is complex and then $g$ is conjugate linear in the second variable $w$ and complex linear in the first variable $v$.

Comment: All that is saying that $g$ is a sesquilinear form, which does hold.  However, this is not equivalent to conjugate symmetry (aka being Hermitian).  Every complex sesquilinear form can be written as the sum of a Hermitian form and an anti-Hermitian form.  The Hermitian component is determined by the polarization identity, but the anti-Hermitian component need not be zero (which you must assume to make your identity valid).

Comment: @qman The polarization identity holds for sesquilinear forms... you don't have to assume that the form is Hermitian.

Comment: @qman: Explicitly, $g(x + y, x + y) - g(x - y, x - y) = 2(g(x,y) + g(y,x))$ while $g(x + iy, x + iy) - g(x - iy, x - iy) = 2i(g(y,x) - g(x,y)$ so $\frac{1}{4} \sum_{j = 0}^3 i^j g(x + i^j y, x + i^j y) = \frac{1}{4} \left( 2(g(x,y) + g(y,x)) - 2(g(y,x) - g(x,y)) \right) = \frac{1}{4} (4 g(x,y)) = g(x,y)$. No conjugate symmetry assumption was used.

Comment: Okay, got it.  I apologize for being so dense.  I must have confused a sign when I tried this earlier.  So the sesquilinear form is fully determined by the induced pseudo-quadratic form.  Thanks.